# How do I keep the buttons of my clothes from unraveling/fraying?

Tags: clothing

With many shirts and sweaters with buttons I find that over the period of usage the threads inside the buttons start to unravel. Eventually this causes the button to pop off unexpectedly. **How can I keep the threads of the buttons from unraveling?**

Removing the thread and stitching back is an option, but finding the exact color thread is difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[**1. Nail polish**](http://life.hackaday.com/use-nail-polish-to-keep-button-threads-from-fraying/)

Apply a coat of clear transparent nail polish on the holes inside the button. This will seal the threads once it is set. Cut off any loose strands of threads before applying.

[image]

**2. Glue**

This is almost the same method mentioned above, but it is with transparent glue instead.